# Dealing with errors in a file

Tags: c++, file, vector, error-handling

I'm actually trying to learn C++ and I have to write a program that reads a sequence of whitespace-separated integers from a file and then calculates the sum. The exercise itslef isn't hard and I came up with this function to read data froma a file :

```
// read whitespace-separated integers from a file 
void fill_from_file(vector<int>& integers, const string& name)
{
    ifstream ist{ name }; 
    if (!ist) error("Can't open input file : ", name); 

    for (int i; ist >> i;) integers.push_back(i); 

}
```

So basically I just keep reading integers from a file until end of file. I have learnt the basics of dealing with files by using the Stroustrup's book programming principles and practice using C++, but I have some doubts about error handling when dealing with files.

The author in his examples along the chapter just shows dealing with error in files with throwing an exception, instead of writing input loops where he tries to recover from a failed read like when we get input from the keyboard.

**Q1)** What is the best approach when dealing with format errors when reading data from a file ? For example, suppose that instead of an integer my function finds an 'x', should I try to recover from this error ? Or should I just give up and abandon the attempt to read more data from that file?

**Q2**Another example : In this same program but with input from cin the author shows the use of a skip_to_int() function that, after a failed read, skips characters until it finds an integer. Would this kind of approach be worth for a file too ? Is this approach worth for a simple program like this ?

Comment: I would say that in a simple program like this, there's no practical point in attempting to recover. *On the other hand*, a simple program like this is also a very good place to practice it. So, my answer would be yes *and* no to all questions ;-)

Comment: @molbdnilo I will try to write a ski_to_int() function also for this program. Thank you ;)